# Series convergence of $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \frac{cos(n \alpha)}{n^{\frac{1}{3}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Any hints on how to check the convergence of $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \frac{cos(n \alpha)}{n^{\frac{1}{3}}}$ would be much appriciated!

Comment: Dirichlet test.

Comment: Is the series of partial sums bounded?

Comment: Try to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\begin{align}&\bullet\;\;\;\sum_{n=0}^k\cos n\alpha=\frac{\cos\frac{k\alpha}2\;\sin\frac{(k+1)\alpha}2}{\sin\frac\alpha2}\\{}\\
&\bullet\;\;\;\frac1{n^{1/3}}\ge\frac1{(n+1)^{1/3}}\;\;,\;\;\;\;\frac1{n^{1/3}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\end{align}$$